# Some troubles with C++ template pointer-to-member based property realization

Tags: c++, templates, properties

My target was to make properties in C++ like in C# - with non-trivial set/get behavior.
Here, object of Property holds refs to master of the prop and its set/get methods.

Realisation, content of Property.h:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

namespace First {

    template <class Master, class Type>
    struct Property
    {
        Master &master;

        const Type (Master::*&get) () const;
        Type (Master::*&set)(Type value);

        Property
        (
            Master &master, 
            const Type (Master::*get) () const, 
            Type (Master::*set)(Type value)
        ): 
            get(get), 
            set(set), 
            master(master) 
        { }

        operator const Type() const { cout << "inside" << endl; return (master.*get)(); }

        Type operator = (Type value)
        {
            return (master.*set)(value);
        }
    };

    // Test chamber.
    class R
    {
        float x;
        const float getx() const { cout << "returning " << 0 << endl; return 0; }
        float setx(float value) { cout << "setting " << value << " in place of " << x << endl; return x = value; }
    public:
        Property<R, float> X;

        R(): X(*this, &R::getx, &R::setx) { }
    };

}
```

I also created .cpp file:

```
#include "Property.h"

using namespace First;

int main()
{
    R r;

    r.X = 10;

    float y = r.X;

}
```

The program makes "assign" step, printing 'setting 0 to 10', but segfaults on call to "retrieve" step, no difference what code (or no at all) inside 'R::getx()'.

```
~/Sources$ ./a.out          

setting 10 in place of 0
inside
zsh: segmentation fault  ./a.out
```

It seems that call to (master.*get()) itself causes a failure. What is wrong in this code?

UPD: A tested out that any other call to master's functions leads to segfault, only one call of (master.*set) successes. Seems that this call invalidates state of object, member-to-ptr, Property itself or Moon phase.

Comment: You've already been given the correct answer. I would also suggest that you make your `Property::master` a pointer rather than a reference, otherwise `Property` is non-copyable as would be any class using it.

Comment: @ZeroArcan: No. The call to `(master.*set)(value)` is also a problem. Its just that you don't get to see the problem, unluckily.

Comment: @Nicola: it wont be copyable whenever master is ref or pointer - I should override copy ctor of containing object to get valid effect.

Comment: @ZeroArcan: Well, yes, the default copy constructor wouldn't make sense, and classes using your `Property` class must be careful about implementing it correctly, but if `master` is a reference there just is no way to make the enclosing class copyable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
const Type (Master::*&get) () const;
Type (Master::*&set)(Type value);
```

Remove `&` from the above definitions. Because of `&`, each of these bound to the constructor parameters which do not exist after the constructor returns.

Also note that it seems that `(master.*set)(value)` works, its because you're *unlucky*. Its actually invokes undefined behavior. But you're lucky that very soon you come to know the problem when `(master.*get)()` fails, giving segfault.

Use:

```
const Type (Master::*get) () const;
Type (Master::*set)(Type value);
```

It should work now, without any problem, as it would cause *copy* of the addresses in the initialization-list, rather than referring to the parameters!

- segfault : http://ideone.com/46RrU (your original code)
- no fault  : http://ideone.com/PljI4 (after fixing)

Comment: @ZeroArcan: You know what *reference in C++* means?

Comment: The other name. I understood now.